# How to avoid the repetition of the word "goal" in this sentence?

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction, formal-language

> The macro goals are set based on what you wanna achieve in next few weeks or months. What's the overall purpose of your work. It can have many layers, such as a week goal based on a month one which in turn is based on a year goal.

Should I avoid the repetition of "*goal*" in the last clause or the use of "*one*" is enough to mitigate the awkwardness? The sentence sounds a little off to me, but I don't know how to fix it.

Also, in my question I use the word *clause* to separate the structure of my phrase because I don't know a better way to describe it. Does clause makes sense in this context? Is there a word that fits better?

---

Based on the feedback I received I changed the sentence to:

> The macro goals are set based on what you want to achieve in next few weeks or months. What's the overall purpose of your work. It can have many layers, such as a weekly goal based on a monthly one which in turn is based on a yearly one.

Comment: Don't use "wanna" in writing unless you are trying to represent someone's careless speech. You could combine the last uses as "weekly, monthly and yearly goals".

Comment: Thank you for the "wanna" correction. I'm afraid if I combine the words as you suggest it won't pass the connection between each step. I want to express that each macro goal is based on a larger one.

Comment: I changed my text a little bit, can I add it to my question?

Comment: Maybe you could turn it around, as "a yearly goal, with monthly and weekly targets". I'm a little surprised by that use of "macro". It usually means the higher level, rather than the lower.

Comment: If you're asking if you can edit your question, yes, people do that all the time.

Comment: I use macro in this context, because, previously I define micro goals as based on what you gonna achieve in a specific session of study.

Comment: I understand now.

Comment: Also "What's the overall purpose of your work." is a question and needs a question mark

Comment: The words you are looking for are ones like "intermediate," "hierarchical," "short term," and "long term,"  but I doubt that people who accept "wanna" and "gonna" will understand such words. Even if you have to repeat yourself with the word "goal," I'd stay concrete with "daily," "weekly," "monthly," etc.